# Validate a PHP form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am writing a PHP script to practice PHP form validation with Javascript.
What I am expecting is the form to be validate by the function `validate()` specified in the `onsubmit` attribute,  but instead I am redirected to the page **`adduser.php`** specified in the **action** attribute

I don't see what I've missed. Any help will be very welcomed.

```js
function validate(form) {

  alert("Inside validate form")
  return false
}
```

```css
.signup {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font: normal 14px Helvetica;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<table class="signup" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
  <th colspan="2" align="center">Signup Form</th>
  <form action="adduser.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <tr>
      <td>Forename</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" maxlength="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" maxlength="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" maxlength="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="64"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Signup">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no such things as a *PHP form*. Do you mean *HTML form* instead ?

Comment: Have you checked for JS errors in the browser's developer console?

Comment: Your code works as designed in the snippet created here

Comment: Better is to have `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) { if (someWrongInputError) { alert("You need to do ...");  e.preventDefault(); } })` instead of the inline onsubmit

Comment: @Cid OK HTML form, I know you understand my question. Just to put accent on the fact that I'm in a context of PHP

Comment: @Thank you Nico Haase, I haven't checked the JS error in the browser, I found an error and I correct it; It works

Comment: @ElomAtsouAgboka Feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You are probably missing a `this.preventDefault()`, because the default action is to actually submit the form.

What you want to accomplish is called 'client-side validation', and while useful, should not replace server side (PHP) validation, because you can never trust the input from a client.

Comment: The code works. The `return false` and `return validate(this)` does the job on the client

Comment: Effectively the code works. In fact the error was cause by the original content of the validate function. The validate function call six other function and among one of them there was an error. I correct it. It works fine

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is expected. When the submit button is clicked the `validate` function is executed, followed by the default behavior of redirecting to the specified `action`.

In order to perform client-side validation, you need to prevent this default behavior by adding `form.preventDefault()`. After that, perform the validation and do the redirect yourself by adding `window.location.href = "adduser.php"`.

Comment: The code works. The `return false` and `return validate(this)` does the job on the client. No need for redirection in the validate function which will not have the values unless grabbed by the script

Comment: Better code is of course to move the onsubmit into an external event handler and use preventDefault when an error is detected

Comment: I don't see an error. The only thing that don't make sense is y u have return on ur 'onsubmit' attribute.  

https://jsfiddle.net/fgxq9hae/

To test html, J's and css it's always ideal to put it on jsfiddle and share the link.

Comment: Not necessary, It works without `form.preventDefault()`